# How to stylize custom classes in Qt using external style sheets?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I have the following codes for my application-

file headerArea.cpp

```
void MainWindow::createDocks(){
    //TOP DOCK OR TITLEBAR
    titleBar = new headerArea();
    addDockWidget(Qt::TopDockWidgetArea,titleBar);
}

void headerArea::paintEvent (QPaintEvent *){
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init (this);
    QPainter p (this);
    style ()->drawPrimitive (QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
}
```

and in my style sheet-

```
headerArea#titleBar{
    background: #ccc;
}
```

The style sheet doesn't seem to work on my application. It doesn't even work for-

```
headerArea{
    background: #ccc;
}
```

But it works fine when I apply the style to the parent class QDockWidget which the class headerArea inherits from-

```
QDockWidget{
    background: #ccc;
}
```

I'd really appreciate any kind of help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should call `headerArea`'s base class `paintEvent()` in `headerArea::paintEvent`.

Comment: you mean to put-
this->parentWidget()->paintEvent();
inside headerArea::paintEvent() function.. right?

Comment: Call `QDockWidget::paintEvent(event)` if `headerArea` is `QDockWidget`'s descendant.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't used your **QDockWidget**, but how I write style for my qss file is, for exmpale QToolButton

```
QToolButton {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS", sans-serif ;
  font-size:1.0em;
  color:#fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background:qlineargradient(spread:pad,x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:1,stop:0 #565656, stop:1 #000);
```

}

```
QToolButton:checked {
  border: 1px outset #424242;
  background:qlineargradient(spread:pad,x1:1,y1:1,x2:1,y2:0,stop:0 #424242, stop:1 #6e6e6e);
```

}

```
QToolButton#buttonNameOne:disabled{
   background-color: #d5d5d5;
   color: #6ba722;
 }
```

And you can set the style sheet path as setStyleSheet(stylesheetpath+'#buttonNameOne').
Hope this help you